# Communication between 2 containers on same host

Tags: mysql, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have to set a test environment where I have one web app container and one MySql container. The web app connects to MySql DB to fetch some data to show. I have written a docker compose file and when I execute it create the 2 containers in same bridge network, but still, I am not able to access the DB from web app container. I am running this on AWS EC2 Amazon Linux machine. Although I can connect to the DB from the server with same user credentials.

```
    version: '2'
services:
  consul:
    image: "gliderlabs/consul-server"
    command: "-server -bootstrap"
    hostname: consul
    container_name: consul
    ports:
     - "8400:8400"
     - "8500:8500"
     - "172.17.0.1:53:8600/udp"
    networks:
     - my_net
  registrator:
    image: "gliderlabs/registrator"
    command: "-internal consul://172.17.0.1:8500"
    container_name: registrator
    hostname: registrator
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - consul
    networks:
     - my_net
  db:
    image: "mysql:5.5"
    container_name: mysql
    hostname: mysql
    volumes:
       - ./mydb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxx
    depends_on:
      - registrator
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
     - my_net
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
      - consul
    ports:
     - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    networks:
     - my_net
networks:
  my_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Connection Code:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host='{0}'.format(db_host),user="root",passwd="xxxx",db="mysql")
    if cnx.is_connected():
        print(' Success! Connected to MySQL database')

db_host = will be taken from consul dns query
```

I am getting the correct bridge IP of mysql container from consul dns query.

Comment: Show us the compose file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Post your docker-compose file and also the connection string details being used in your web app container.

Comment: @johnharris85 , Tarun Lalwani, added the docker compose file.

Comment: What is the error? Connection refused, host not found, etc?

Comment: Hi Thanks all. I am able to connect my MySql container. There was a problem with my python code indentation.